# How can I time-switch a few loads very precisely?

Tags: switches, timer

Let's say there are 5 different loads, and I need a circuit to switch them on/off based on a pre-tunable delay. (E.g. first one immediately, second one exactly 2.78 seconds after the first one, third one 5.33 seconds after the second, the 4th load 0.24 seconds after the third, and the last one 1.05 seconds after the 4th). 0.01 seconds precision is enough.

The time delay between each one needs to be adjustable (not during the circuit operation, but using variable resistors ,manually, before turning on the main circuit).

**Can this be done without oscillators or pulse counting stuff?**

I can measure the circuit results precisely using other methods (to test if I've tuned the delays close enough to desired times.)
I'll repeat the run-measure-tune cycle enough times to reach the 0.01s precision.

Comment: Assuming you want an accuracy of 10ms in a period of up to 10s, "Using variable resistors" is going to be a serious problem in itself! They're just not that accurate normally AND they suffer from temperature drift. You'll need special high-precision multi-turn pots with a vernier dial. If your constraint is no microcontrollers you need to say why.

Comment: you need a microcontroller, or lots of experience and patience.

Comment: @pjc50 I was considering costs. Seems I'm wrong.

Comment: Back of the envelope assessment - you want a range of ~10s with a precision of 0.01s.  That means your design has to be accurate/precise to 1 part in 10,000.  This needs to be  digital solution.

Comment: @Elementronic analogue control systems went out in the 70s because, even then, doing anything with a precision of more than about 1% became very difficult and expensive.

Comment: "repeat the run-measure-tune cycle enough times to reach the 0.01s precision" doesn't work for resistors unless you compensate for temperature somehow. 0.01% might be achievable, but then you have to consider capacitors which are even worse. And the slightest bit of electrical noise will ruin it.

Answer (score 2):

> Can this be done without oscillators or pulse counting stuff?

Yes, but it's going to be difficult to get the precision you want.  A circuit using several 555 timer ICs will do the job but you'll have to spend time trimming all your resistor and capacitor values to get the timing as you want.  But "yes", it could be done.

If this were my problem, I'd opt to use a low cost microcontroller to do this.

Comment: ... well, until the temperature changes.

Comment: I guess I forgot to mention "temperature controlled chamber" to the mix!  But yes, it's going to be very difficult indeed!  Not impossible, just a lot of work for very little gain IMHO.